# What is the probability of the Head appearing exactly twice if a coin is flipped thrice?

Tags: probability

> $1$. **What is the probability of the Head appearing exactly twice if a coin is flipped thrice?**
>
> **Solution**: There are total $8$ combinations of Head and Tail if a coin is flipped thrice, where $2$ heads appear only thrice. So, the probability is, $\frac{3}{8}$.

.

> $2.$ **What is the probability of the Head appearing in all three occasions if a coin is flipped thrice?**
>
> **Solution**: $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8} $

How can I solve #$1$ in the $2$<sup>nd</sup> method?

Comment: They can.  Just write out all the possibilities and count.  It's just that the second one is easier, so you don't have to look at all the possibilities if you understand the 'rule of multiplication' in probability.

Comment: Just want to add that this can represent a Binomial distribution. Consider that each flip of the coin or roll of the dice is distributed by a Bernoulli trial with probability $\frac 1{No. of sides}$

Comment: “Thrice”??  What century is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the formula in almost all such type of problems *$^nC_k.p^k.q^{n-k}$*

where $n=$number of times the coin flipped

$p=$ the probability that the coin landed head which is always $p=\frac12$

$q=$ the probability that the coin landed tail which is always $q=\frac12$

$k=$number of outcomes (Here we need **two** heads as outcome)

In this case $p=\frac12,q=\frac12,n=3,k=2$

1) $$^3C_2.\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2.\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3-2}$$
$$^3C_2.\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2.\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac38$$

2)

Here $P(E)=\frac{n(E)}{n(S)}$

where $n(S)=2^3=8$, we took $2^3$ because we need all the three heads

$n(E)=1$, since there is only way to get all the heads in $3$ flips that is $H,H,H$

S0, the answer is $\frac18$

**Or in another way**

1) The possibilities with two heads are

$HHT$

$HTH$

$THH$

All the other possibilities are

$HHT$

$HTH$

$THH$

$HHH$

$TTT$

$TTH$

$THT$

$HTH$
So, there are $8$ total possibilities but we want only $2$ heads when coin is flipped thrice.

So, the probability is $\frac38$

Comment: Do you agree with @Conal's solution?

Comment: @yahoo.com That is another approach. But in most of the such problems you can directly calculate the answer using that formula.

Comment: @yahoo.com tien Lee’s is more well written than mine

Answer (score 3):

You could use Combinations for example for the first question it would be:

$^3C_2 \times \frac12\times \frac12\times \frac12$

Which is:

$3\times \frac12\times \frac12\times \frac12 = \frac38$

The second question would be:

$^3C_3\times \frac12\times \frac12\times \frac12$

Which is:

$1\times \frac12\times \frac12\times \frac12 = \frac18$

Comment: Can you kindly supply me with some citation regarding the technique/formula you used here?